# Find rank of parametered matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Today, I've got task: **Find all values of parameter a, when rank of matrix M equals 2**, where matrix M is 3x3 and has some dependencies on a, for example:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & a^2-1\\
1-a & 5 & 7 \\
2a+3 & 2 & 1+a^2
\end{pmatrix}$$

It is not very complicated task, so I found determinant of matrix, which is polynom. Then I found nulls of polynom and checked if these nulls correspond to rank 2.

But what if I have super-big matrix, with noncalculating determinant, like 4x4 =) Or what if determinant equation is some kind of complicated?

So the question is: are there other ways to solve this task, which may be scalable for bigger problem?

Comment: for calculating the determinant of a big matrix you could use the laplace formula (which reduces the problem to finding the determinants of submatrices). You can also use some tricks to check if the polynomial has multiple roots (for example: a polynomial $f$ has multiple roots iff the greatest common divisor of $f$ and $f'$ is not a unit (assuming we work over a field))